# How can I retrieve the original content in a page via REST API, content that I pushed myself also via API?

Tags: rest-api, html, content

I pushed some content in pure plain-text into a wordpress via the REST API.

Say I push this page `content`:

```
Hello.

Bye.
```

Then when I retrieve it, instead of this original content I find a property called `content.rendered` that contains something like this:

```
<p>Hello.</p>
<p>Bye.</p>
```

Is pushing content "destructive"? I mean... is it rendered on `POST` and the original content lost forever so no wat to `GET` it again? Or may I retrieve the "original" somehow?

Answer (score 1):

To get the raw content, you need to pass the `context` [argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments) as `edit`. This is the version of the content that's used in the editor, and should match the raw data you originally sent. This version of the content will be accessible at `content.raw`.

Note that using this context may require the request to be [authenticated](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), as the current user will need permission to edit the post to see the raw content.